# Parse JSON in ActionScript 2

Tags: json, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

My school has a flash document we play across the TV's around the school. It has a schedule and time. It animates to different layouts and is supposed to have weather. It was made ages ago in ActionScript 2. As of now, the weather part doesn't work. It used to pull info in from a weather sevrer out school has, but I can't figure out how to do that. I'm just trying to pull in from Yahoo Weather or forecast.io at this point. They output to JSON but I can not for the life of me find a way to do this in Action Script 2. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: i think you will need to find a custom json parser in as2 maybe like >> [this one](https://github.com/earth911/search-api-sample-code-as2/blob/master/JSON.as) <<

Answer (score 0):

Are you pulling the values directly into Flash or are they being run through an intermediary aspx/PHP page first?  If it is going through an intermediary server first, then you can use either of those language's native JSON parsers.  Otherwise, you're gonna have to use an AS2 parser, or write your own (fun exercise!!!)